# t-sql combine column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Based on the following table

```
ID  Description  ReleateID 
-----------------------------------
1   some desc1.   50
1   some desc1.   60
2   some desc2.   50
2   some desc2.   70
3   some desc3.   80
```

How to get the following output

```
ID  Description   AllRelatedIDs
----------------------------------
1   some desc1.   50,60
2   some desc2.   50,70
3   some desc3.   80
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the FOR XML trick:

```
SELECT t.id, 
       t.description
       STUFF(ISNULL(SELECT ', ' + x.releateid
                      FROM TABLE x
                     WHERE x.id = t.id
                       AND x.description = t.description
                   FOR XML PATH ('')), ''), 1, 2, '')
  FROM TABLE t
```